# Get specific content from facts API Python

Tags: python, json

This is my current code:

```
limit = 1
api_url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/facts?limit={}'.format(limit)
response = requests.get(api_url, headers={'X-Api-Key': API_KEY})

print(response.text)
```

I get this returned:

> [{"fact": "The Canadian province of New Brunswick had a bloodless war with the US state of Maine in 1839"}]

I only want to print the fact.

`response.fact` doesn't exist

```
print(response.fact)
```

I also tried loading the JSON file

```
import json

fact_load = json.load(response.json())
print(fact_load['fact'])
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: try `fact_load = json.loads(response.json())` note the s at the end of loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response text is just a text string. You can load the json reprenation usually by just using the `.json()` function on the request.

The JSON will provide you a list of facts (as shown by the `[]` surrounding the response)

When exporting the JSON representation it will also interpret the json object as a dict, and because Python doesn't directly let you use dot notation to get properties of a dictionary you can use several methods of extracting the data.

My preference for this sort of thing would be `response.json()[0].get("fact", "")` as you get to control the failure condition where fact wasn't a key in the dictionary.

Alternatively if you know "fact" is going to be a key, you can just do `response.json()[0]["fact"]`

Answer (score 1):

Got it

```
print(response.json()[0]['fact'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me inspect the error.

```
print(fact_load['fact'])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

This means that the fact_load is a list object.
And to get content of a list obj, one must access with integer index.
But you tried to access with a string.

The correct answer is must be as follows.

```
print(fact_load[0]['fact'])
(while fact_load[0] is a dict)
```